# How can I stop an infinite loop after every 1000 values?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

/* I want to see the maximum value of short int.I want to see it using loops only.So I created an infinite loop.The question is that I want to stop the loop to see the values after every 1000 values.But it stops only when the loop reaches 1000,because I have given it to stop using if condition,then it never stops.What can I do so that it stops after every 1000 values.Program is given below*/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
     //Short int is declared intentionally      
     short int d=0;
     char i;
     //Infinite loop is created intentionally       
     for(d=0; ;d++)                
     {
         //printing value                   
         printf("\n%d",d);                  

         //stopping a loop when value reaches 1000
         if(d==1000)
         {
            //continuing after pressing a character after 1000                      
            printf("\n press i to continue");
            scanf("%d",&i);
            continue;
         }                
     }                  
     //see the output
     getch();
}
```

Comment: that's why you should check the return value of scanf...

Comment: Try using the modulo operator, '%', as in `if ((d % 1000) == 0)`.

Comment: You should still set up an input to check if it is to break out of the loop to end it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will stop after every 1000 values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    //Short int is declared intentionally
    short int d=0;
    char i;
    //Infinite loop is created intentionally
    for(d=0; ;d++)
    {
        //printing value
        printf("\n%d",d);

        //stopping a loop when value reaches 1000
        if(d%1000 == 0 && d != 0)
        {
            //continuing after pressing a character after 1000
            printf("\n press any key to continue...");
            scanf("%c",&i);
            continue;
        }
     }
     //see the output
     getch();
}
```

and you are using a wrong format specifier([See](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c.html)). `%c` for single character.
`scanf("%d",&i);` this statement should be `scanf("%c",&i);`. And the condition will be `if(d%1000 == 0 && d != 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

You're using wrong format specifier to scan a `char` value. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should change

```
 scanf("%d",&i);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&i);
```

That said, to stop on *every* 1000 iteration, you need to change `if(d==1000)` to `if( (d % 1000) == 0)`.

FWIW,

1. `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to coform to the standards.
2. signed integer type overflow is again UB. You should rather not rely on that. use `<limits.h>` to check the range, if any.

Comment: if( (d%1000) ==1000).. how is it even possible..?? This will always fail for any number. Perhaps you meant if( (d%1000) ==0)

Answer (score 0):

You just check the Condition as follows

Very important point is you have to compare with zero and it will work fine.

```
if( (d%1000 == 0)
  {
  //continuing after pressing a character after 1000                        
  printf("\n press i to continue");
  scanf("%c",&i);
  continue;
  }
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
if(d==1000)
```

to

```
if!(d%1000)
```